# How can I adjust the distribution of my Stack View for unequal view sizes?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uistackview

Here is what I have so far for my Main.Storyboard, along with the View Controller Scene hierarchy and Stack View settings.

[image: Main.Storyboard]

Right now, everything scales correctly for each device and orientation. The problem is when I attempt to adjust the stack view distribution. I want the middle "CLICK" button to be a little smaller and for the UIImageView to be slightly larger. Changing the distribution setting to "Fill" or "Fill Proportionally" didn't help. It simply cut off the top pencil view when I ran the app. Manually adjusting the top, middle and bottom view sizes doesn't help either.

Comment: You want "Top" and "Bottom" to be equal heights, and "Middle" to be shorter? Do you want it to be a fixed height value? Or, do you want it to be, say, 50% of the height of "Top"?

Comment: @DonMag It would be nice to have the top and bottom image views each to take up 40%  of the height and for the middle button to take up the remaining 20%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your Stack View's Distribution to `Fill`

Give the `Top` view a height constraint equal to the height of the stack view, with a multiplier of `0.4`

Give the `Bottom` view a height constraint equal to `Top`

And that should do it!

**Edit**

Ctrl-click-drag from `Top` to `Stack View`, select `Equal Heights`:

[image]

Ctrl-click-drag from `Bottom` to `Top`, select `Equal Heights`:

[image]

Select `Top` and edit the Height constraint in the **Size Inspector** pane:

[image]

Select `Bottom`  and edit the Height constraint in the **Size Inspector** pane:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot find any height constant or multiplier settings.

Comment: Whoops.... **Ctrl**-click-drag (I had written right-click) -- on second thought, right-click-drag works also.